Need a suggestion for how can I do a score based neural network without a target
I have an input of 25. I want an output of 14, which represents 7 targets for 7 enemies (7 pairs of 2 values). Based on that output, I compute a score. (I need to use the output in another area) I want a neural network to try to maximize this score. Basically I don't have a target. Where can I find usefull documentation regarding that? Preferably python, but anything works.
Tried a feed forward neural network with 3 hidden layers. Made another hidden layer which is the output and instead of the normal activation function, I though of using my function to calculate the score, but I got stuck.
I can't find any usefull documentation on tensorflow that does not have a target and I don't know how to modify the score function to get what I need.
I am ready for any negative feedback and sorry in advance.

For the part without the target, you can use unsupervised learning and reinforcement learning models. There are several types of those networks, e.g., autoencoders, GANs, SOMs, etc. Can you post your code for your feed-forward MLP?

The feed-forward is unreadable. I will look now into the unsupervised learning algorithms, will come back shortly.
